# Is it possible to have a dual boot in a laptop with raid 0 + ssd?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, raid

First of all, I'm lost here.

I'm looking for a new laptop and it has: 2TB (2x 1TB PCIe M.2 SSD) RAID0 [Boot] + 512GB PCIe M.2 SSD [Storage]

It comes with Windows installed, but I'd like to have a linux. I'm thinking to have linux in 512GB storage and let RAID0 as is.

is it possible?

Thanks, and sorry if my question does not make sense.

Comment: You are asking for a yes or a no and that is not the goal for askubuntu. If you have a problem you can ask about that problem but that would require for you to already own the system and having a problem settings this up ;-)  Besides that we also do not support hardware recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux doesn't seem to like "fakeraid" which is what your machine would have. Only a server grade Raid card with a processor on it will run hardware raid and present it to the OS as a single drive. You CAN install ubuntu server and make a linux raid array (software raid) which is what I have done, 2 PCIe 4.0 M.2 SSD drives in raid 0 (11.7 GB/sec!) but that's not what you are asking. If you want to install linux on the 512GB M.2 I see no reason why you can't. Not exactly sure how you would get grub to recognize windows on the raid, but again it's not actual raid until the windows raid driver loads so the /boot-efi partition is on one of those drives. Personally I would boot to a live CD and look at what's going on with gparted (you may have to install it in the live kernel (once booted open a terminal and "sudo apt install gparted") From there you can see how windows is actually using the drives. I haven't done a dual boot in years, like over 10, so I can't be much help there but I am very familiar with raid, both hardware and software. My guess is your grub install will either go on the 512 or one of the 1tb drives that has windows boot partition would be my guess. If you have no data on the 512 what do you have to lose by trying? Just fire up an install disk or usb and choose "other" when asked about where to install and follow the prompts. I would make a windows boot usb drive before doing anything just in case you somehow mess up windows.